# What were the bolts on Frankenstein's Monster for?

Tags: frankensteins-monster, mary-shelley

We've all seen them, but what were they for? Were they fasteners used to hold Mary Shelley's creature's head on, which would be suspicious, since she didn't use bolts to attach it's limbs, or were they merely used as conduits to route the energy needed to reanimate Dr. Frankenstein's creation?

Comment: I don't think Mary Shelley came up with the bolts.  They seem like a Hollywood addition.

Comment: @Wad_Cheber, can confirm, wrote an essay on the fact xD incidentally too much English Literature is making me desperate to edit "monster" in the title to "creature" hah

Answer (score 41, accepted):

[This article](http://alanbrookland.com/2009/10/27/the-man-who-invented-frankensteins-monsters-bolt/) credits *The man who invented Frankenstein's Monster's Bolt* to [Jack Pierce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Pierce_%28make-up_artist%29) a make-up artist for the classic Hollywood adaptation. The bolts themselves are described as:

> "actually **electrodes used to conduct the electricity** used to bring the monster to life."

Answer (score 4):

The bolts, green complexion and low IQ are all attributes that were added in the films. In the original gothic novel, Shelley's creature is loving, well-read, and intelligent. He becomes vengeful and monstrous only after his repeated attempts at acceptance and love are rejected.

Answer (score 0):

I think it was a way to transfer the electricity from the lightning through the creature's body, and into it's heart, reanimating it thusly

Comment: Do you have anything extra that isn't covered in NominSim's answer?